# ¿Cómo utilizar lombok?

Tags: spring-boot, lombok

Tras realizar los siguientes pasos no se que tengo quehacer para utilizar lombok en mi proyecto.
¿Me podéis ayudar?

1. Instalo lombok
2. Ejecute el jar desde al cmd: java -jar lombok.jar
3. Seleccione mi IDE de desarrollo y le da a Finalizar.
4. Añadí el jar manualmente a mi proyecto. (External JARS).
5. Modifique el pom para que quedase de la sigueinte forma:

   ```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
   ```

y por otro lado:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

¿Cómo puedo ahora en mis modelos de datos utilizar esta herramienta?

Answer (score 0):

La forma descrita por la documentación oficial para usarlo es la siguiente:

Necesitas que lombok esté presente a la hora de compilar pero no es necesario durante la ejecución, puedes añadirlo como dependencia así:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <!-- Si usas Spring boot, omite la versión ya que Spring la provee -->
    <version>1.18.22</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Al excluirlo del plugin, le estás diciendo a Spring que no lo use durante la compilación como annotattion processor, que es justo lo opuesto de lo que necesitas.

La web de Baeldung, como suele ser habitual, ofrece un pequeño ejemplo de cómo usar [Spring y Lombok](https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-with-lombok-part-1/) (en inglés).

Answer (score 0):

Con que agregues la dependencia como `provider` seria suficiente, luego depende del IDE que utilices debes de instalar un complemento.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.22</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Para saber que hacer en cada IDE ve a la pagina `https://projectlombok.org/` en el menu click en `install > IDEs` ahi seleccionar el que estés utilizando y te dirá los pasos para activarlo, después el IDE reconocerá las anotaciones de Lombok.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]